# Virt-Manager Error

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've installed **QEMU-KVM** and **Virt-manager** according to this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-set-up-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux.

I can get pretty far until I reach step 4 of 5 when creating a new VM:

```
Uncaught error validating install parameters: Requested operation is not valid: storage pool 'default' is not active
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1902, in _validate
return self._validate_storage_page()
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2218, in _validate_storage_page
self._guest.name, do_log=True)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2210, in _get_storage_path
path = self._addstorage.get_default_path(vmname)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addstorage.py", line 235, in get_default_path
suffix=suffix, collidelist=newcollidelist)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/storage.py", line 588, in find_free_name
pool_object.refresh(0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3229, in refresh
if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virStoragePoolRefresh() failed', pool=self)
libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid: storage pool 'default' is not active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage pool must be active before the storage it contains can be used.

By default the storage pool named `default` is active and autostarted, but it might have been reconfigured on your system.

You can start it yourself with `virsh`, e.g., to start the pool:

```
sudo virsh pool-start default
```

And to mark the pool as autostarted at boot time:

```
sudo virsh pool-autostart default
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for helping a beginner!