# I deleted the Libvirt user, and now virt-manager throws `Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.`

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I understand this wasn't smart, just looking to find out how to fix it.

Full error message:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.

Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running.

Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1036, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 144, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 104, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reconfigure LibVirt package to run post installation script:

- For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you need to run:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure libvirt-bin
  ```
- For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you need to run:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure libvirtd-daemon-system
  ```

Comment: I'm on 18.10, and the daemon is not installed under that name. Looks like `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libvirt-daemon-system` cleared that error message, but now I'm seeing a different one. Thanks, I think you put me on the right track though.

Comment: Looks like I also needed to `$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/libvirt/images` and also get the `default` pool started per this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094660/virt-manager-error Sorted now. Thank you!